# Divergence of the product of a tensor and a vector field

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis, tensors

Let $\mathbf u$ and $\mathbf S$ be smooth fields with $\mathbf u$ vector valued and $\mathbf S$ tensor valued. I would like to prove the following identity:

$$\operatorname{div}\mathbf S\mathbf{u}=\mathbf S^T\cdot\operatorname{grad}\mathbf u+\mathbf u\cdot\operatorname{div}\mathbf S$$

**My attempt:**

\begin{align}
\operatorname{div}\mathbf S\mathbf{u}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}(S_{ij}u_j)\mathbf{e}_j&=\frac{\partial S_{ij}}{\partial x_i}u_j\mathbf{e}_j+S_{ij}\frac{\partial u_j}{\partial x_i}\mathbf{e}_j\\
&=\frac{\partial S_{ij}}{\partial x_i}u_j\mathbf{e}_j+S_{ji}^T\frac{\partial u_j}{\partial x_i}\mathbf{e}_j\\
&=\mathbf u\cdot\operatorname{div}\mathbf S+S_{ji}^T\frac{\partial u_j}{\partial x_i}\mathbf{e}_j
\end{align}

Here, I have used the following definition: $\operatorname{div}\mathbf S=\frac{\partial S_{ij}}{\partial x_i}\mathbf{e}_j$.

But I am stuck on the last expression, $S_{ji}^T\frac{\partial u_j}{\partial x_i}\mathbf{e}_j$, since the definition of the gradient of a vector field is $\operatorname{grad}\mathbf u=\frac{\partial u_j}{\partial x_i}\mathbf{e}_i$.

I would appreciate any help or hint. Thank you.

Comment: You should only have two of the same index in a term when using summation convention. Also, you should have the same free indices on both sides of an equation, which you don't in several places.

Comment: And what sort of product is $\mathbf{Su}$? Is it an inner product $S_{ij}u_j$ or an outer product $S_{ij}u_k$?

Comment: @Chappers It is a inner product. As for your first comment I follow the definitions of my lecture notes so I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: For operators like div and grad use `\operatorname`, not `\mathrm`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming $\mathbf{S}$ is a matrix and $\mathbf{u}$ is a vector, then $\operatorname{div}\mathbf{Su}$ is a scalar. Hence, we have
\begin{align}
\operatorname{div}\mathbf{Su} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}(S_{ij}u_j) = \frac{\partial S_{ij}}{\partial x_i}u_j+S_{ij}\frac{\partial u_j}{\partial x_i}.
\end{align}

Note that
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial S_{ij}}{\partial x_i}u_j=\frac{\partial S_{ij}}{\partial x_i}\mathbf{e}_j\cdot u_j\mathbf{e}_j=\mathbf{u}\cdot \operatorname{div}\mathbf{S}.
\end{align}
Next, observe
\begin{align}
S_{ij}\frac{\partial u_j}{\partial x_i}= \sum_j \sum_i S_{ij}\frac{\partial u_j}{\partial x_i} = \sum_j \sum_i S_{ji}^Tu_{j, i} = \mathbf{S}^T\cdot \operatorname{grad}\mathbf{u}.
\end{align}
Here we used the fact that
\begin{align}
\text{d}\mathbf{u}= (\operatorname{grad}\mathbf{u})^T 
\end{align}
otherwise, we would have the expression
\begin{align}
\text{d}\mathbf{u}\cdot \mathbf{S}.
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

I think, the right expression is:

$$\operatorname{div}(\mathbf{A} \mathbf{v})=\mathbf{v} \cdot \operatorname{div} \mathbf{A}^{\top}+\operatorname{tr}(\mathbf{A} \mathrm{g r a d}\mathbf{v}).$$

II found it [here](http://homepages.engineering.auckland.ac.nz/%7Epkel015/SolidMechanicsBooks/Part_III/Chapter_1_Vectors_Tensors/Vectors_Tensors_14_Tensor_Calculus.pdf) and in a slightly different form [here](https://sundoc.bibliothek.uni-halle.de/habil-online/06/06H055/t7.pdf).

First of all, $\operatorname{div}(\mathbf{A})$ and $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{A}$ are equal only for symmetric tensors (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence#Tensor_field)), since

$$
\operatorname{div}(\mathbf{A})=\frac{\partial A_{i k}}{\partial x_{k}} \mathbf{e}_{i}=A_{i k, k} \mathbf{e}_{i}=\left[\begin{array}{l}
\frac{\partial A_{11}}{\partial x_{1}}+\frac{\partial A_{12}}{\partial x_{2}}+\frac{\partial A_{13}}{\partial x_{3}} \\
\frac{\partial A_{21}}{\partial x_{1}}+\frac{\partial A_{22}}{\partial x_{2}}+\frac{\partial A_{23}}{\partial x_{3}} \\
\frac{\partial A_{31}}{\partial x_{1}}+\frac{\partial A_{32}}{\partial x_{2}}+\frac{\partial A_{33}}{\partial x_{3}}
\end{array}\right]
$$
and
$$
\nabla \cdot \mathbf{A}=\frac{\partial A_{k i}}{\partial x_{k}} \mathbf{e}_{i}=A_{k i, k} \mathbf{e}_{i}=\left[\begin{array}{l}
\frac{\partial A_{11}}{\partial x_{1}}+\frac{\partial A_{21}}{\partial x_{2}}+\frac{\partial A_{31}}{\partial x_{3}} \\
\frac{\partial A_{12}}{\partial x_{1}}+\frac{\partial A_{22}}{\partial x_{2}}+\frac{\partial A_{32}}{\partial x_{3}} \\
\frac{\partial A_{13}}{\partial x_{1}}+\frac{\partial A_{23}}{\partial x_{2}}+\frac{\partial A_{33}}{\partial x_{3}}
\end{array}\right].
$$
We have a relation $\operatorname{div}(\mathbf{A}^{\top}) = \nabla \cdot \mathbf{A}$

Below is the proof of $\operatorname{div}(\mathbf{A} \mathbf{v})=\mathbf{v} \cdot \operatorname{div} \mathbf{A}^{\top}+\operatorname{tr}(\mathbf{A} \mathrm{g r a d}\mathbf{v})$ in Cartesian coordinate system:
$$
\operatorname{div}(\mathbf{A u})=\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{i}}\left(A_{i j} v_{j}\right)=\frac{\partial A_{i j}}{\partial x_{i}} v_{j}+A_{i j} \frac{\partial v_{j}}{\partial x_{i}}
$$
For the first term we have:
$$
\begin{array}{c}
\frac{\partial A_{i j}}{\partial x_{i}} v_{j}=\frac{\partial A_{1 j}}{\partial x_{1}} v_{j}+\frac{\partial A_{2 j}}{\partial x_{2}} v_{j}+\frac{\partial A_{3 j}}{\partial x_{3}} v_{j} \\
=\frac{\partial A_{11}}{\partial x_{1}} v_{1}+\frac{\partial A_{12}}{\partial x_{1}} v_{2}+\frac{\partial A_{13}}{\partial x_{1}} v_{3}+\frac{\partial A_{21}}{\partial x_{2}} v_{1}+\frac{\partial A_{22}}{\partial x_{2}} v_{2}+\frac{\partial A_{23}}{\partial x_{2}} v_{3}+\frac{\partial A_{31}}{\partial x_{3}} v_{1}+\frac{\partial A_{32}}{\partial x_{3}} v_{2} \\
+\frac{\partial A_{33}}{\partial x_{3}} v_{3}= \\
\frac{\partial A_{11}}{\partial x_{1}} v_{1}+\frac{\partial A_{21}}{\partial x_{2}} v_{1}+\frac{\partial A_{31}}{\partial x_{3}} v_{1}+\frac{\partial A_{12}}{\partial x_{1}} v_{2}+\frac{\partial A_{22}}{\partial x_{2}} v_{2}+\frac{\partial A_{32}}{\partial x_{3}} v_{2}+\frac{\partial A_{13}}{\partial x_{1}} v_{3}+\frac{\partial A_{23}}{\partial x_{2}} v_{3}+\frac{\partial A_{33}}{\partial x_{3}} v_{3}= \\
v_{1}\left(\frac{\partial A_{11}}{\partial x_{1}}+\frac{\partial A_{21}}{\partial x_{2}}+\frac{\partial A_{31}}{\partial x_{3}}\right)+v_{2}\left(\frac{\partial A_{12}}{\partial x_{1}}+\frac{\partial A_{22}}{\partial x_{2}}+\frac{\partial A_{32}}{\partial x_{3}}\right)+v_{3}\left(\frac{\partial A_{13}}{\partial x_{1}}+\frac{\partial A_{23}}{\partial x_{2}}+\frac{\partial A_{33}}{\partial x_{3}}\right)= \\
\left(\begin{array}{l}
\frac{\partial A_{11}}{\partial x_{1}}+\frac{\partial A_{21}}{\partial x_{2}}+\frac{\partial A_{31}}{\partial x_{3}} \\
\frac{\partial A_{12}}{\partial x_{1}}+\frac{\partial A_{22}}{\partial x_{2}}+\frac{\partial A_{32}}{\partial x_{3}} \\
\frac{\partial A_{13}}{\partial x_{1}}+\frac{\partial A_{23}}{\partial x_{2}}+\frac{\partial A_{33}}{\partial x_{3}}
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{l}
v_{1} \\
v_{2} \\
v_{3}
\end{array}\right)=\operatorname{div}\left(\mathbf{A}^{\mathrm{T}}\right) \cdot \mathbf{v}
\end{array}
$$
And for the second term:
$$
\begin{aligned}
A_{i j} \frac{\partial v_{j}}{\partial x_{i}}=\sum_{j=1}^{j=3}(&\left.A_{1 j} \frac{\partial v_{j}}{\partial x_{1}}+A_{2 j} \frac{\partial v_{j}}{\partial x_{2}}+A_{3 j} \frac{\partial v_{j}}{\partial x_{3}}\right) \\
&=A_{11} \frac{\partial v_{1}}{\partial x_{1}}+A_{21} \frac{\partial v_{1}}{\partial x_{2}}+A_{31} \frac{\partial v_{1}}{\partial x_{3}}+A_{12} \frac{\partial v_{2}}{\partial x_{1}}+A_{22} \frac{\partial v_{2}}{\partial x_{2}}+A_{32} \frac{\partial v_{2}}{\partial x_{3}}+A_{13} \frac{\partial v_{3}}{\partial x_{1}}+A_{23} \frac{\partial v_{3}}{\partial x_{2}} \\
&+A_{33} \frac{\partial v_{3}}{\partial x_{3}}
\end{aligned}
$$
Now, if we consider the product
$$
\mathbf{T} = \left(\begin{array}{lll}
A_{11} & A_{12} & A_{13} \\
A_{21} & A_{22} & A_{23} \\
A_{31} & A_{32} & A_{33}
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{lll}
\frac{\partial v_{1}}{\partial x_{1}} & \frac{\partial v_{1}}{\partial x_{2}} & \frac{\partial v_{1}}{\partial x_{3}} \\
\frac{\partial v_{2}}{\partial x_{1}} & \frac{\partial v_{2}}{\partial x_{2}} & \frac{\partial v_{2}}{\partial x_{3}} \\
\frac{\partial v_{3}}{\partial x_{1}} & \frac{\partial v_{3}}{\partial x_{2}} & \frac{\partial v_{3}}{\partial x_{3}}
\end{array}\right)
$$
then $A_{11} \frac{\partial v_{1}}{\partial x_{1}} + A_{12} \frac{\partial v_{2}}{\partial x_{1}} + A_{13} \frac{\partial v_{3}}{\partial x_{1}}$ are correspondingly (1,1), $A_{21} \frac{\partial v_{1}}{\partial x_{2}} + A_{22} \frac{\partial v_{2}}{\partial x_{2}} + A_{23} \frac{\partial v_{3}}{\partial x_{2}}$  - (2,2) and $A_{31} \frac{\partial v_{1}}{\partial x_{3}} + A_{32} \frac{\partial v_{2}}{\partial x_{3}} + A_{33} \frac{\partial v_{3}}{\partial x_{3}}$ - (3,3) elements of  $\mathbf{T}$. Thus,  $A_{i j} \frac{\partial v_{j}}{\partial x_{i}}=\operatorname{tr}(\mathbf{A} \mathrm{g r a d} \mathbf{v})$.

But I don't know how to prove this for any coordinate system...

Answer (score 1):

I agree with [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4116402), but I think it would be better to demonstrate the answer in a tensorial way.

Assuming that $\textbf{S}$ is a second order tensor and $\textbf{u}$ a first order tensor (vector), we have:
$$
\text{div} \left(\textbf{S} \cdot \textbf{u} \right) =
\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \left( S_{ij} u_j \right) =
\dfrac{\partial S_{ij}}{\partial x_i} u_j + S_{ij}\dfrac{\partial u_{j}}{\partial x_i}
$$
$$
\text{div} \left(\textbf{S} \cdot \textbf{u} \right) =
\text{div} \left(\textbf{S}^T\right) \cdot \textbf{u} + \textbf{S} : \left(\text{grad} \ \textbf{u}\right)^T
$$
or, equivalently,
$$
\text{div} \left(\textbf{S} \cdot \textbf{u} \right) =
\textbf{u} \cdot \text{div} \left(\textbf{S}^T\right) + \text{tr}\left(\textbf{S} \cdot \text{grad} \ \textbf{u}\right)
$$
where, considering two second order tensors $\textbf{A}$ and $\textbf{B}$, the double dot product is defined as follows:
$$
\textbf{A} : \textbf{B} = A_{ij}B_{ij}
$$
** Note that $\textbf{A} : \textbf{B}$ can be defined in two different ways ([see this post](https://sbrisard.github.io/posts/20140219-on_the_double_dot_product.html)).

It is known, but worth to remark, that dot product between first order tensors commute. From the first term on the right in the equations above, we have:
$$
\text{div} \left(\textbf{S}^T\right) \cdot \textbf{u} =
\dfrac{\partial S_{ij}}{\partial x_i} \underline{e}_j \cdot u_k \underline{e}_k =
\dfrac{\partial S_{ij}}{\partial x_i} u_j,
$$
but also
$$
\textbf{u} \cdot \text{div} \left(\textbf{S}^T\right) = u_i\underline{e}_i \cdot \dfrac{\partial S_{lk}}{\partial x_l}\underline{e}_k = u_i \dfrac{\partial S_{ji}}{\partial x_j} = \dfrac{\partial S_{ij}}{\partial x_i} u_j
$$
As a result, $\text{div} \left(\textbf{S}^T\right) \cdot \textbf{u} = \textbf{u} \cdot \text{div} \left(\textbf{S}^T\right) $.

In order to demonstrate the equality $(\textbf{S} : \left(\text{grad} \ \textbf{u}\right)^T = \text{tr}\left(\textbf{S} \cdot \text{grad} \ \textbf{u}\right))$, note that:
$$
\text{tr}\left(\textbf{S} \cdot \text{grad} \ \textbf{u}\right) =
\left( \textbf{S} \cdot \text{grad} \ \textbf{u} \right) : \textbf{1} =
\left(S_{ij} \underline{e}_i \otimes \underline{e}_{j} \cdot \dfrac{\partial u_k}{\partial x_l} \underline{e}_{k} \otimes \underline{e}_{l} \right) : \underline{e}_{p}\otimes \underline{e}_{p}
$$
$$
\text{tr}\left(\textbf{S} \cdot \text{grad} \ \textbf{u}\right) =
\left(S_{ij} \dfrac{\partial u_j}{\partial x_l} \underline{e}_{i} \otimes \underline{e}_{l} \right) : \underline{e}_{p}\otimes \underline{e}_{p} =
S_{ij}\dfrac{\partial u_{j}}{\partial x_i}
$$
and
$$
\textbf{S} : \left(\text{grad} \ \textbf{u}\right)^T =
S_{ij} \underline{e}_i \otimes \underline{e}_{j} : \dfrac{\partial u_l}{\partial x_k} \underline{e}_k \otimes \underline{e}_{l} =
S_{ij}\dfrac{\partial u_{j}}{\partial x_i}
$$
The references cited by [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4116402) are very good, by the way.